# Testing Chainlink API calls using Hardhat

Tags: ethereum, solidity, hardhat, chainlink

I am having trouble testing Chainlink API calls locally. I have a contract which calls my API consumer contract to make an API call. However, when I try to do that, the MockOracle (mocked oracle for local testing, from chainlink) contract reverts (VM exception) saying "Must use whitelisted functions". I am making an API call for a bytes32 get request.

This is the function modifier (inside of LinkTokenReceiver) where the MockOracle reverts (it gets called by the MockOracle when receiving LINK tokens):

```
/**
   * @dev Reverts if the given data does not begin with the `oracleRequest` function selector
   * @param _data The data payload of the request
   */
  modifier permittedFunctionsForLINK(bytes memory _data) {
    bytes4 funcSelector;
    assembly {
      // solhint-disable-next-line avoid-low-level-calls
      funcSelector := mload(add(_data, 32))
    }
    require(funcSelector == ORACLE_REQUEST_SELECTOR, "Must use whitelisted functions");
    _;
  }
```

The ApiConsumer is properly funded, and the LINK token is a local deployment of the chainlink Token.
So, what am I doing wrong? Or what is the best way to test Chainlink API calls (bytes32 get request) locally using hardhat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Chainlink oracle workflow, consumers are basically supposed to send a request to the off-chain oracle node so that the oracle node can fetch data from the API specified by consumers. In the workflow, request sent by user must be caught by off-chain oracle node.

What you are doing here is to send your request to smart contract `oracle` and the `oracle` save your request into event log `oracleRequest` so that it could be caught by off-chain oracle.

Your problem here is as suggested by modifier `permittedFunctionForLINK`,  the function selector is not `oracleRequest` so that off-chain oracle cannot recognize the request.

I am guessing you are currently using the `oracle.sol` and `ChainlinkClient.sol` in version v0.6. In version v0.6, AFAIK, ChainlinkClient doesn't not help users to add function selector `oracleRequest` in the users' Chainlink request, which means you will get the error if you doesn't manually add the function selector in your request. In v0.7, ChainlinkClient helps you add the selector in the request. Just check the function `sendChainlinkRequestTo` in [ChainlinkClient v0.6](https://github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/blob/develop/contracts/src/v0.6/ChainlinkClient.sol) and [ChainlinkClient v0.7](https://github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/blob/develop/contracts/src/v0.7/ChainlinkClient.sol) by yourself.

Solutions:

1. Use the v0.7 ChainlinkClient and [operator.sol](https://github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/blob/develop/contracts/src/v0.7/Operator.sol)(smart contract oracle.sol is renamed as operator.sol in v0.7) for your test. The document can be found [here](https://docs.chain.link/any-api/get-request/examples/single-word-response).
2. There is a repo called [hardhat-starter-kit](https://github.com/smartcontractkit/hardhat-starter-kit) in Chainlink official github, there are sample codes you can try. Or you can directly use starterkit to test AnyApi and any other services.

Answer (score 0):

If you are testing locally the chainlink node will not be able to detect any requests. 
You have a few options:

1. Deploy your APIConsumer contract to a testnet and make use of an
   already deployed operator contract. A list can be found on
   chainlinks website
   [https://docs.chain.link/any-api/testnet-oracles/]. Then select a
   jobId for a node job that can provide the API data you need e.g.
   bytes32, Int, multi words etc. The jobId can be specified in your APIConsumer contract.
2. Deploy your own operator contract, setup your own node (chainlink has an option for setting up temporary development nodes), and then create a custom job for your API. You will then need to put you node address as an authorised sender in your operator contract to permit data to be returned from your node.
3. For local testing you will need to write a function in your test script that sends a
   mock response to your mock operator contract. Make sure you setAuthorisedSenders for the account you use to send the fulfillOracleRequest transaction, to test properly I'd recommend using a second account from you local testing environment for testing purposes instead on the one used for deployment. You will
   need to listen to the initial request data transaction event from
   your APIConsumer contract to get the requestId value and also if you are using fulfillOracleRequest2 for a multi value API call listen for the
   the chainlink requested event from your mock operator contract to
   retrieve any other values you might need such as 'expiration', to
   enable you to create a transaction for the fulfill function on the
   mock operator contract. 
   If using fulfillOracleRequest2 for multi response, may need to modify your mock operator validateMultiWordResponseId function a bit to enable the modifier to pass (Solidity doesnt like comparing strings or different data types), trick is to remove the .offset (my compiler does not like this as it only works with storage values) assignment to the new variable and just keccak256
   abi.encodePacked both requestIds from the fulfill arguments and
   calldata then compare them together. See below:

```js
  modifier validateMultiWordResponseId(bytes32 requestId, bytes calldata _data) {
    require(_data.length >= 32, "Response must be > 32 bytes"); 
    bytes memory firstDataWord = new bytes(32);
    for(uint256 i=0; i<=31; i++){
      firstDataWord[i] = _data[i];
    }
    requestIdToBytes = string(abi.encodePacked(requestId));
    requestIdFromCalldata = string(abi.encodePacked(firstDataWord));

    require(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(requestIdToBytes)) == keccak256(abi.encodePacked(requestIdFromCalldata)), "First word must be requestId");
    _;
  }
```

```html
//Typescript snippet for test script 
//If local network - Set Authorised senders on Mock Oracle to account[1]
    const [owner, mockNode] = await ethers.getSigners();
    const mockNodeAccount = mockNode.address
    await mockOracle.setAuthorizedSenders([mockNodeAccount])
    
    
    const transaction: ContractTransaction = await apiConsumer.requestWithWords(ANY_ARGS_FOR_API)
    const transactionReceipt: ContractReceipt = await transaction.wait(1)
    const requestId = transactionReceipt.events[0].topics[1]

    const apiFilter = apiConsumer.filters.ChainlinkRequested()
    const apiEvents = await apiConsumer.queryFilter(apiFilter)
    console.log(apiEvents)

    const filter = mockOracle.filters.OracleRequest()
    const events = await mockOracle.queryFilter(filter)
    const {specId, requester, requestIdEvent, payment, callbackAddr, callbackFunctionId, cancelExpiration, dataVersion, data} = events[0].args
    
    const encodeMwr = web3.eth.abi.encodeParameters(
        ['bytes32','int256','int256','int256','string','string'],
        [requestId, '123', '456', '789', 'text', 'moreText'])


    const encodeRequestId = web3.eth.abi.encodeParameters(
        ['bytes32'],
        [requestId])
        
    await mockOracle.connect(mockNode).fulfillOracleRequest2(requestIdfirst, payment, callbackAddr, callbackFunctionId, cancelExpiration, encodeMwr)
```

To improve on this you could then look to add an API http GET call into your test script for getting the rest of the callback data for fulfillOracleRequest or fulfillOracleRequest2 function.